# Hello "${world}" vs "Hello ${world}" which one is a better practise in bash script?

Tags: bash

`Hello "${world}"`
`"Hello ${world}"`  in bash script should behave the same, but which one of them is a better practise?

Something like `"${base_dir}"/"${filename}"` looks ugly, right?

Comment: `looks ugly, right?` Looks fine for me.

Comment: In the general case, depends on what you mean. `echo` specifically is not a particularly good example because it often doesn't matter if your arguments are separate strings; for many other commands, it's a lot more crucial. If you don't know exactly what you mean, usually quoting everything is the better approach. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 4):

The command `echo Hello "${world}"` takes two arguments: "Hello" and whatever string the variable `world` is set to. It outputs them with a single space between them.

You have more control over the output by giving `echo` a single string argument. For example, if you want a tab instead of a space, you can enter a tab character between the words of the passed string: `echo "Hello<tab>${world}"` whereas you'd get a space if you give them as separate arguments.

The command `echo "${base_dir}"/"${filename}"` takes a single argument, because there are no space separators. There is no reason not to use `echo "${base_dir}/${filename}"`.